Lenovo T460s shutdown when first battery run out under Ubuntu 24.04

I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a Lenovo T460s. I notice earlier that the Laptop shut down unexpectedly. Few moment after, i have checked that, when the second battery of my Laptop runs out, it shut down imediatly.
I have installed some software such Battery Notifier to notify me when the device reach some point of charge. But it not resolve my issue. Is it OS problem or Firmware problem, or even Hardware.
Thanks for helping me.
I have this image.

The laptop shuts off when the battery runs out. Sounds perfectly normal hardware performance.

I have updated the question with an image.

Do you mean, if the main battery has power left, but the second battery runs out, the laptop still shuts down?

Yes exactly @ArchismanPanigrahi . Its the case.
